# How to use a cordovawebview in nativescript

Tags: native, nativescript, hybrid, cordovawebview

Has someone succeeded in using a cordovawebview in nativescript ? I can easily use a webview, but it seems not to support cordova. I need to build a mixed native/hybrid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve with NativeScript to where you would even need Cordova? I can't imagine a need where you'd need Cordova at all embedded inside NativeScript and even if you did you'd bloat your app size with unecessary Cordova stuff. So I'm really curious what you're trying to achieve. Also, if you're getting into NativeScript, it's best if you just forget all about Cordova. Trying to think of Cordova or the web hybrid won't get you far with NativeScript, React Native, or Xamarin. That's my opinion of course.

Comment: What specifically do you need from the cordova/phonegap side that isn't provided via plugins in NativeScript.   I've developed apps on both Cordova and NativeScript; and haven't seen any reason to embed the Cordova engine into NS.

Comment: Ok i understand. But it's because i have a cordova one that works well and only make some parts native

Comment: If i understood anyway i could make a plugin for this..but would that be easy as making a webview based one ?

Comment: There already is a webview built into NativeScript that you can use for any web view type stuff.  You don't have to make a plugin for the webview.  And, yes someone could make a cordova webview plugin for NativeScript and I'm sure it would work fine...